# Preventing Questions from being repeated in Qualtrics?

Tags: repeat, qualtrics

I'm using Qualtrics to display images in blocks. Part 1 should show 1 of 3 images from set 1 and then 1 of three images from set 2 (this occurs three times).

Is there a way to prevent the image that occurred from set 1 in part one from appearing in parts 2 and 3? I want every image to occur once, without being repeated.

Comment: Post the code with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use blocks and order randomization, but it's not really clear what you're asking.